# How can I build a twitter-like, semi-transparent background overlay?

Tags: css, twitter, overlay, opacity

I referring to the semi-transparent, white border around a [Twitter page](https://twitter.com/RealSkipBayless/status/210933175684313088)'s main content. It is the white border that extends all the way up to the header.

Just wondering if anyone has a quick demo handy to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with css3. Make a div:

```
<div class="container transparent">
  Your content
</div>
```

Then in your stylesheet(fixed now):

```
.transparent {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Looking at the source for that twitter page though, it looks like they used a transparent png:

```
background: url(https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339096274/t1/img/wash-white-30.png);
```

Comment: -@GorillaMcD, thanks, hmm, can you play with this to help: http://jsfiddle.net/SwvNt/1/

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. While you could do the transparent png, support for rgba is widespread enough nowadays that, IMO, it's ok to use it over a transparent png. Apparently, it didn't like the "0" and spaces in the rgba method. You could also use background-color the same way.

Comment: Haha, I take that back. I spelled rgba wrong (it was rbga). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

The newest Twitter update makes it so only the following will allow your Twitter to become transparent... http://userstyles.org/styles/75782/newtwitter-semi-transparent-stream-and-dash-v0-2